# regarding date picker iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a datepicker to appear on the tap of a textfield. I have managed to to that. Now I have two problems:
1. It shows date and time both. I need only date.
2. I need the picker to disappear if I tap somewhere in the background.

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

     [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     [self.text1 setInputView:datePicker];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.text1.inputView;
        self.text1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
```

I have used   `datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;` but still I'm getting the time as well. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the description of date to textField, use NSDateFormatter to convert the date from datePicker.

To dismiss you can add a tapGestureRecognizer to your view or you can add an accessoryInputView to your textField

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer  = [UITapGestureRecognizer new];
    [tapRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapView:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

}

- (void)didTapView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer{
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

OR

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UIToolbar *toolbar =[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,44)];
    toolbar.barStyle =UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                 target:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                 target:self
                                                                                 action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                               target:self
                                                                               action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    [toolbar setItems:@[cancelButton,flexibleSpace, doneButton]];

    _activeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *yeardate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
//Set this yeardate to your datepicker.
[datePicker setDate:[dateFormat dateFromString:yeardate]];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do I set yeardate to my datePicker? sorry I'm still new here.

Comment: Sorry to say this doesn't work. It is still showing time. And the date picker itself started showing time too. When I ran my code, the date picker showeed only the date but the textfield contained both date and time

Comment: I just truncated the string that was supposed to get displayed in the text field. I now have only the date. But the date that is getting shown on the textfield shows the date of the day previous to the one selected, ie, if I select 9th May, it shows 8th May. How can I resolve that?

Comment: this is due to the timezone.